# Why generate HikariProxyConnection by javaassist since author already write ProxyConnection?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp, javassist

According to the source code of HikariCP, I found the author generates HikariProxyConnection by javaassist, but the class do nothing but invoke the super class method.

For example, the HikariProxyConnection's super class is ProxyConnection:

```
public class HikariProxyConnection extends ProxyConnection implements AutoCloseable, Connection, Wrapper {
   public Statement createStatement() throws SQLException {
     try {
        return super.createStatement();
     } catch (SQLException var2) {
        throw this.checkException(var2);
     }
   }

   public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String var1) throws SQLException {
     try {
         return super.prepareStatement(var1);
     } catch (SQLException var3) {
         throw this.checkException(var3);
     }
   }    }
```

I found ProxyConnection already do a lot of things, HikariProxyConnection only add a try catch block to every method.

It would be nice if anyone can give an explanation.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer on this, but I recall reading that Hikari uses javassist to act at the bytecode level as a performance optimization. Using bytecode, they can make the JVM perform method calls statically (as fast as possible), whereas if they go the decorator pattern route (i.e. wrapper class), the JVM has to do a dynamic dispatch of the method calls (method overloading resolution, ...).

Comment: There's a new answer(by author @brettwooldridge):

A concrete class is generated from the abstract ProxyConnection class. Any methods that are not "overridden" by the abstract class, and that throw SQLException have delegates generated with the following code:

... which allows us to inspect the exception to see if it represents a disconnection error.

A side-effect is that, yes, the code ends of being flexible with respect to JDBC API changes -- at least all that we have encountered so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Hikari issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1198) on the purpose of `HikariProxyConnection` answered by @brettwooldridge :

> The proxies delegate to the real driver classes. Some proxies, like the one for ResultSet, only intercept a few methods. Without the code generation, the proxy would have to implement all 50+ methods which simply delegate to the wrapped instance.
>
> Code generation, based on reflection, also means that nothing needs to be done when a new JDK version introduces new JDBC methods to existing interfaces.

Comment: I have already seen it. but i can't understand this answer. The ProxyConnection will change when JDK version introduces new JDBC methods to existing interfaces. not means that nothing needs to be done

Comment: Although the ProxyConnection is a abstract class, as a connection-pooling, must impl this method in fact. Generate these class just for compatible with high version JDK?

Comment: @lucare I suggest you add a comment to the issue to get an "official" response